# How to list atime for files?

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd, ls, stat

According to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/234162/464470) can `stat` be used to give the `atime` on Linux, but FreeBSD 10.1 doesn't have the GNU `stat`.

How do I list the `atime` for files?

Comment: According to [this manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat(1)), FreeBSD's stat should contain the same functionality.

Comment: @jordanm GNU coreutils `stat` also gives you access, modify, and change times, and it's by default, no extra arguments to make it happen (checked with coreutils version 8.26)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ls -lu
```

where `-l` will provide a long listing format 
and `-u` will sort by access time.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used:

```
ls -l -u
```

Alternatively - maybe break out perl?

Perl can use the [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) syscall directly

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
foreach my $filename ( @ARGV ) {
    print "$filename =>", (stat($filename))[8],"\n";
}
```

You can one-liner this as:

```
perl -e 'print "$_ ",(stat($_))[8],"\n" for @ARGV' <filename(s)>
```

If you want to do a prettier timestamp (rather than epoch which is what `stat` returns):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print "$_ ",Time::Piece->new((stat($_))[8]),"\n" for @ARGV'
```

or

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print "$_ ",Time::Piece->new((stat($_))[8])->strftime("%F %T"),"\n" for @ARGV'
```

Which uses `strftime` and `%F %T` to give you:

```
2015-09-06 01:02:33
```

Expanding the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece; 
foreach my $filename ( @ARGV ) {
    my $epoch_time = (stat($filename))[8];
    my $time_string = Time::Piece -> new ( $epoch_time ) -> strftime ( "%F %T" );
    print "$time_string => $filename\n";
}
```

Comment: FreeBSD's `ls` doesn't have `--time`.

Comment: OK. Updated with an alternative :)

Answer (score 2):

With [FreeBSD stat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat(1)):

```
stat -f '%Sa' file
```

`%Sa` mean you want file `a`ccess time as `S`tring.